# How to download an .EXE file from a website?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing an application where i required to download an exe file from a website. 
I am using Visual studio express 2008.

I am using the following code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new   Uri("http://example.com/images/def.exe"), @"d:\ac\def.exe");           
}
```

The def.exe get downloaded in Ac folder of D drive but is of 0 byte.

I am not able to understand that why it is happening.

Please help me.

Comment: Have you checked what's going over the wire, with a tool like [Fiddler](http://fiddlertool.com)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can alter your code a bit to get it working.  `DownloadFileAsync` is asynchronous call so may be your thread executing it ending before your download has completed.

You need to attach a handler to find out if the download has completed if you are using async

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDownload()
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += webClient_DownloadProgressChanged;
        webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://www.telerik.com/downloads/productfiles/btmba/TelerikJustDecompileSetup_2014.3.1021.0.exe"), @"c:\temp\justdecompile.exe");

        // just to show in a Unit Test.. Not required in actual code
        Thread.Sleep(10000); 

        var info = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\justdecompile.exe");
        Assert.IsTrue(info.Length > 0);
    }
```

Your handler can look like,

```
    void webClient_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}    downloaded {1} of {2} bytes. {3} % complete...",
                    (string)e.UserState,
                    e.BytesReceived,
                    e.TotalBytesToReceive,
                    e.ProgressPercentage));
    }
```

Comment: my file is approximately 6 MB of size. i am trying Your code but not compiling . Gives me error No overload for method 'WriteLine' takes '5' arguments

Comment: Apologies.. change this to `Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}    downloaded {1} of {2} bytes. {3} % complete...",
                    (string)e.UserState,
                    e.BytesReceived,
                    e.TotalBytesToReceive,
                    e.ProgressPercentage));`

Comment: @Flanker, the code definitely downloads the exe file.  In the unit test, you can increase the thread sleep time in case you have slower internet connection.  Do you see any bytes getting downloaded in the Output window in VS?

Comment: when i paste the url in adress bar it prompt me Save file Dialog. i think this mighty be the problem?? @Punit Ganshani MVP

Comment: No, that is default behavior of browser when it gets specific content type.

Answer (score 4):

The `DownloadFileAsync` method runs *asynchronously*, that means, it returns as soon as the download has started. If you want to wait for it to end, you have to subscribe the `DownloadFileCompleted` event.

Of course, you can also use the synchronous method, like this:

```
webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://example.com/images/def.exe"), @"d:\ac\def.exe");
```

Comment: with downloadfileAsync i am getting above 0 byte exe file. without using async it gives me error 404. @Frank

Comment: In your question, you told us you get 0 bytes. 404 means the file is not there. Can you verify that your URL is correct?

Comment: i know that but it is working fine with async but without it giving me error 404. but file is present there.

Comment: What happens when you copy/paste the URL in your browser?

Comment: the save dialog pops up and when i press save button my exe got downloaded at selected path @lucrativelcues

Comment: Let's continue this in a chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68015/room-to-help-flanker

Comment: please help me to solve it . i have tried following code but not done