# C# checkbox direct download file

Tags: c#, checkbox, download

I have trouble assinging a download to checkbox , for starters in the event of checking to download a specific file in the current folder. I plan to add cancel+delete on unchecked later... if I get this working
The problem is that it creates an empty file , but the download never occurs.
I really want it to download on check, without using a separate button that triggers the event.

```
public void downloadFile(String address, String filename)
    {
        WebClient down = new WebClient();
        down.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(address), filename);
    }
    private void Autor_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        downloadFile("https://live.sysinternals.com/autoruns.exe", "autoruns.exe");
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download an .EXE file from a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689565/how-to-download-an-exe-file-from-a-website)

Comment: You should put the `DownloadFileAsync` in a `try/catch` block.  And update your question with the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. It seems NF 3.5 doesn't support TLS 1.2 by default wich was requiered for sysinternals to accept the connection.
Had to adjust my code to:

```
public void downloadFile(String address, String filename)
    {
        WebClient down = new WebClient();
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
        down.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(address), filename);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing where the file is supposed to be downloaded to.  This would download it to C:\test:

```
down.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://live.sysinternals.com/autoruns.exe"), @"C:\test\autoruns.exe");
```

Though you'll probably want to know when it finishes, so you'll have to add handlers as well.

Comment: That wasn't the issue. If not path given it is downloaded in the app folder. The issue seems to be the link itself. While it downloads perfectly in browser, it doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: So, what happens then exactly?  Using that code I get the autoruns.exe file.  Same file-size as downloading via a web-browser.

Comment: just a file called autoruns.exe of 0kb is created. Ccleaner link portable and it gets downloaded without any issue

Comment: I get the file as intended, have you tried capturing the error messages?  Or adding a handler for DownloadFileCompleted ?  https://imgur.com/a/j2M6lu4 is what I get and it works fine.

Comment: how would I go about capturing the error messages? Not sure what's wrong. Tried different links for other tools, and the only ones that cause this problem are the ones from live.sysinternals.com

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534704/how-to-deal-with-exceptions-when-using-webclient-downloadfileasync

Comment: unfortunately my project needs to be netframework 3.5, so "await" is not available...